# Show that there exists an integer $n$ such that $a+nb$ is a primitive element of the field $K=F(a,b)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, separable-extension

Let $F$ be a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ be algebraic elements over $F$. Show that there exists an integer $n$ such that $a+nb$ is a primitive element of the field $K=F(a,b)$.

We know that the characteristic of the subfield is same as that of the field and hence $char\; F=0$ implies $F(a,b)$ is separable extension. Now, also $F(a,b)$ is a finite extension and hence $K/F$ has a primitive element (since it is finite and separable extension). So, the existence of a primitive element is guaranteed.

But how do I show the existence of integer $n$ such that $a+nb$ is a primitive element of the field $K=F(a,b)$.
Can someone please help me ? Thankyou.

Comment: Is this not a part of a standard proof of the existence of a primitive element? The sum $a+cb$, with $c$ ranging over $F$, is a primitive element of $K/F$ except for possibly finitely many choices of $c$.

Comment: **A finite algebraic extension $L$ of $K$, there is an element α ∈ L such that
$L = K(α)$.** Proof of this theorem will help you to what your desire.